# What is the Grant Permissions button for Azure AD web app

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

This more of an admin question as far as where you might find this issue. I am working with an Azure AD web app and I am wondering what the `Grant Permissions` button does?

I made a test dummy MVC project to see what it did and when I grant permissions for my account for the current directory it makes the manifest unusable.

This is the view of my app in Azure AD app registrations. I've highlighted the Grant Permissions button that I am talking about.
[image]

This is the drop down I get when clicking on the Grant Permissions button. This is the part I really don't understand and need clarification on what it's doing when I say yes.
[image]

Basically, what can I do to undo the actions if I say yes to the Grant Permissions button for my app? But also, what exactly does the Grant Permissions do for my app? I am just a normal user in my Active Directory that has the ability to create apps in ad and edit the manifest.

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Grant Permissions* button in the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com) will perform Admin Consent on the app you have selected.

Admin Consent can accomplish a multitude of things. There are two primary use cases.

1. If you're building a single tenant web app that calls admin and user scopes/permissions, it will consent for all users in that tenant.  This will let the app call any admin scopes, and also suppress consent for all the users inside the tenant.
2. The other use case is to consent for app only permissions, which always requires admin consent.

The [Azure AD How to build a multi tenant app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-devhowto-multi-tenant-overview#understanding-user-and-admin-consent) doc has a great section on the meaning of admin consent.

I am not aware of any way to revoke admin consent. An individual user can revoke consent they've granted through [My App](https://myapps.microsoft.com).

Comment: One trick to remove admin consent would be to delete the application's service principal in the tenant. That would also remove any individual consent that was granted to the application and any tenant specific settings set on the service principal, but that may still be a fine option for you.

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you give any insight as to why the manifest would be un-editable after granting permission?

Comment: @Alex I haven't heard of that happening before. I'll forward this comment to that team and see if they can help.

Comment: @DanielDobalian That would be awesome! I think it might be because I am a normal ad user and not an admin but then again I am still a novice at this. If you find nothing, that is okay, I just wanted to get this issue out to others that might encounter the same problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Alex out of curiosity, how were you able to "Grant Permissions" as a normal user, did an admin do it on your behalf? If you registered the application as a non-admin you should be able to edit the manifest. If you didn't register the app, that may explain this.

Comment: @DanielDobalian I think what you're saying is correct. My admin created an app for me for testing and I think that is why I did not have access. He granted permission on behalf of everyone so yes I don't know how I did not see that before. Thanks for following up on this!